# Angular not posting data to ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I'm trying to send data to my asp.net server with angular. The data at the fron-end part is okay and i have tested it. But for some reason when i try to send these data to my server with a post request, angular sends null data to my server. I tried sending data to my server from postman and it works without any problem and my server send as response **true** as excepted. I don't know what i'm missing inside my front-end...

**Here is my angular code with the post request:**

```
    // Set admin ID to object and create new school
    schoolData.AdminId = 0;
    
    const schoolHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    const schoolBody = schoolData
    this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/CreateSchool", { body: JSON.stringify(schoolBody) }, { headers: schoolHeaders }).subscribe(schoolResponse => {
                
        if (schoolResponse) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }

    }, error => console.error(error));
```

**My asp.net code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Api/CreateSchool")]
    public bool CreateNewSchool([FromBody] SchoolModel schoolData)
    {
        // IT PRINTS THE NAME ONLY FROM POSTMAN NOT IF THE REQUEST IS FROM ANGULAR
        Console.WriteLine("Name is: " + schoolData.Name);
        SchoolManager context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SchoolManager)) as SchoolManager;
        return context.CreateNewSchool(schoolData);
    }
```

Comment: what does `console.log(this.baseUrl);` say in your angular code?

Comment: @lan https://localhost:5001/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `{}` from `{ body: JSON.stringify(schoolBody) }`

Comment: what does the new http.post call look like?